# Getting MTP to work with a Galaxy tab 2 7.0?

Tags: usb, android, mtp

I'm trying to get MTP with the galaxy tab 2 7.0 working on my ubuntu installation. Such that I can access the files.

I tried to do what is described here:

> http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/12/how-to-connect-your-android-ice-cream-sandwich-phone-to-ubuntu-for-file-access

I however fail at executing one of the following commands

```
mtp-detect | grep idVendor
mtp-detect | grep idProduct
```

This fails

```
[20:42|0] $ mtp-detect | grep idVender
Device 0 (VID=04e8 and PID=6860) is a Samsung GT-P7310/P7510/N7000/I9100/Galaxy Tab 7.7/10.1/S2/Nexus/Note.
PTP_ERROR_IO: failed to open session, trying again after resetting USB interface
LIBMTP libusb: Attempt to reset device
LIBMTP PANIC: failed to open session on second attempt
Unable to open raw device 0
[20:44|0] $ mtp-detect | grep idProduct
Device 0 (VID=04e8 and PID=6860) is a Samsung GT-P7310/P7510/N7000/I9100/Galaxy Tab 7.7/10.1/S2/Nexus/Note.
PTP_ERROR_IO: failed to open session, trying again after resetting USB interface
LIBMTP libusb: Attempt to reset device
LIBMTP PANIC: failed to open session on second attempt
Unable to open raw device 0
```

Now my guess was was that the idVender is the same as the VID (04e8) and the idProduct is the same as PID (6860) Now I continued to work with those values and completed the tutorial. When finished I tried

```
android-connect
```

This returned

```
fuse: bad mount point `/media/GalaxyTab': Transport endpoint is not connected
```

Does anybody have a clue what to do? Also I want to note that when I connect my GalaxyTab 2 7.0 that I still get a pop-up of ubuntu that a device was connected. I also can still see the mapstructure, the problem however is is that all the folders have 0 bytes and do not have any subfolders. I can only see the folders in the root.

ps. I also checked a similar question and tried what is described in this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/88630/27480

-- 2012-09-18 -- Edit --
Using go-mtpfs, described in the first answer, http://linuxundich.de/de/android/mit-go-mtpfs-unter-linux-auf-android-handys-via-mtp-zugreifen/, I got the following for my Samsung Galaxy SII

```
[23:21|0] $ go-mtpfs android
2012/09/18 23:21:58 compiled against libmtp 1.1.3
Device 0 (VID=04e8 and PID=6865) is UNKNOWN.
Please report this VID/PID and the device model to the libmtp development team
2012/09/18 23:21:58 device unknown: unknown (04e8:6865) @ bus 1, dev 7
: 
ignoring usb_claim_interface = -6ignoring usb_claim_interface = -5PTP_ERROR_IO: failed to open session, trying again after resetting USB interface
LIBMTP libusb: Attempt to reset device
LIBMTP PANIC: failed to open session on second attempt
2012/09/18 23:22:18 rdev.open: open: open returned nil
```

For the Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7.0 it didnt work either...

```
[23:31|0] $ go-mtpfs android
2012/09/18 23:31:03 compiled against libmtp 1.1.3
Device 0 (VID=04e8 and PID=6860) is a Samsung GT-P7310/P7510/N7000/I9100/Galaxy Tab 7.7/10.1/S2/Nexus/Note.
2012/09/18 23:31:03 device Samsung: GT-P7310/P7510/N7000/I9100/Galaxy Tab 7.7/10.1/S2/Nexus/Note (04e8:6860) @ bus 1, dev 11
: 
PTP_ERROR_IO: failed to open session, trying again after resetting USB interface
LIBMTP libusb: Attempt to reset device
LIBMTP PANIC: failed to open session on second attempt
2012/09/18 23:33:04 rdev.open: open: open returned nil
```

jmtpfs didn't work either :-(

```
[23:42|0] $ jmtpfs ~/android/
Device 0 (VID=04e8 and PID=6860) is a Samsung GT-P7310/P7510/N7000/I9100/Galaxy Tab 7.7/10.1/S2/Nexus/Note.
PTP_ERROR_IO: failed to open session, trying again after resetting USB interface
LIBMTP libusb: Attempt to reset device
LIBMTP PANIC: failed to open session on second attempt
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'MtpErrorCantOpenDevice'
  what():  Can't open device
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting MTP to work with a Galaxy Nexus?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/87667/getting-mtp-to-work-with-a-galaxy-nexus)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** A [GVFS MTP backend](http://intr.overt.org/blog/) is now available. The author also provides a [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~langdalepl/+archive/gvfs-mtp).

---

I have already written about go-mptfs [there](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143350/how-to-get-a-working-mtp-connection-for-galaxy-s2-in-12-04).

The author recently wrote another article with another alternative [jmptfs](http://linuxundich.de/de/ubuntu/mit-jmtpfs-mtp-gerate-wie-das-galaxy-nexus-oder-das-samsung-galaxy-siii-in-ubuntu-mounten/). He is writing in german but I think the commands he uses should be self explanatory, or machine translation would be sufficient.

You can of course just take a look the original project sites:

- https://github.com/hanwen/go-mtpfs
- http://research.jacquette.com/jmtpfs-exchanging-files-between-android-devices-and-linux/

May be one of those work for you.

Comment: Thanks! German is no problem since I can speak and write it fluently ;) I will check your url's tomorrow. I will let you know if it helped.

Comment: Sorry, @LiveWireBT, but either go-mtpfs or jmtpfs didn't work. Installation and compiling went all smooth but when mounting the device they both fail. Both for my Samsung Galaxy SII and Samsung Galaxy Tab 7 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

https://askubuntu.com/a/88630/27480 worked for me.

I was also having a bit of trouble with the steps at first. Rebooting the PC after following the steps solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you would consider alternative techniques, you can use ftp for file transfer.

You should start an ftp server from your Android device with `Software Data Cable`. You can find it at [Software Data Cable app on Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lyy.softdatacable&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5seXkuc29mdGRhdGFjYWJsZSJd). Once downloaded, start the app, on the upper left, tap `Sync PC`, and get the ip adress show in the middle of screen.

Then go to Nautilus and click `File > Connect to server`, then enter the ip adress. Then the contents of your tablet will show up. I have a Galaxy Tab 8.9, and I had problems with mtp too. It's microsoft stuff and it always will be buggy on Linux.

*edit: The sync pc button may be somewhere else in a phone screen, I have tried it only with a tablet.

Answer (score 0):

I tried out [Airdroid](http://airdroid.com) last night and it worked fantastically well with my wife's Google Nexus tablet.

The difference is that airdroid is an app on your device that exposes the devices filesystem for local web access.

Comment: OP's wants MTP to work. Airdroid is not a solution for this. It is just an alternative interface to access files.